# How to encode IP addresses in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, ip, data-mining

I am a newbie in Jupyter notebook (and python). 
This is a sample of the dataset I have:

```
Time    Source  Destination Protocol    Source port Dest port   User-Agent  Accept Encoding Length  Host    Full request URI    Request Method
04:29:02    172.31.64.26    23.219.88.136   HTTP    49454.0 80.0    Microsoft BITS/7.8  identity    333 img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/...   GET
04:29:04    172.31.64.26    23.219.88.136   HTTP    49454.0 80.0    Microsoft BITS/7.8  identity    388 img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/...   GET
04:30:43    172.31.64.26    23.219.88.136   HTTP    49458.0 80.0    Microsoft BITS/7.8  identity    332 img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net http://img-s-msn-com.akamaized.net/tenant/amp/...   GET
04:31:21    172.31.64.26    169.254.169.254 HTTP    49460.0 80.0    aws-sdk-go/1.12.20 (go1.9; windows; amd64)  gzip    202 169.254.169.254 http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instan...   GET
04:31:21    172.31.64.26    169.254.169.254 HTTP    49461.0 80.0    aws-sdk-go/1.12.20 (go1.9; windows; amd64)  gzip    215 169.254.169.254 http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/se...   GET
```

I converted IP addresses and all other attributes into integers, so I can feed them into KNN algorithm using:

```
from functools import reduce
ip2int = lambda ip: reduce(lambda a,b: int(a)*256 + int(b), ip.split('.')) 
df['Source'] = df['Source'].apply(ip2int)
df['Destination'] = df['Destination'].apply(ip2int)
```

Output sample (Please ignore User Agent and Accept Encoding attributes):

```
    Time       Source   Destination Protocol    Source port Dest port   User-Agent  Accept Encoding Length  Host    Full request URI    Request Method
  16142 2887729178  400251016   HTTP    49454.0 80.0    Microsoft BITS/7.8  identity    333 (0, 1325)\t0.2549063512932777\n (0, 60)\t0....  (0, 5188)\t0.30234613640985336\n (0, 17099)...  0
  16144 2887729178  400251016   HTTP    49454.0 80.0    Microsoft BITS/7.8  identity    388 (0, 1325)\t0.2549063512932777\n (0, 60)\t0....  (0, 5188)\t0.30234613640985336\n (0, 17099)...  0
  16243 2887729178  400251016   HTTP    49458.0 80.0    Microsoft BITS/7.8  identity    332 (0, 1325)\t0.2549063512932777\n (0, 60)\t0....  (0, 5188)\t0.30234613640985336\n (0, 17099)...  0
  16281 2887729178  2852039166  HTTP    49460.0 80.0    aws-sdk-go/1.12.20 (go1.9; windows; amd64)  gzip    202 (0, 1325)\t0.2549063512932777\n (0, 60)\t0....  (0, 5188)\t0.30234613640985336\n (0, 17099)...  0
```

However, when I try to fit the training dataset:

```
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = df.iloc[:, 4].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
```

It shows me this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-182-701d38c6b940> in <module>
      5 from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
      6 scaler = StandardScaler()
----> 7 scaler.fit(X_train)


ValueError: could not convert string to float: '169.254.169.254'
```

What did I do wrong? Is it because I didn't convert the dataset into dataframe? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You apparently have strings where you intended to have numbers. Without a minimal example of the original DataFrame it will be hard to help. Pleas read [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Dataset sample is added. As I said before I converted them all into integers, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). We need to be able to copy data and code from your question into an editor so we can test what you have done and any solution we come up with. - Emphasis on **minimal** examples - if only a few columns are need then just those.

Comment: I did what you asked me:) thank you

Comment: The string IP address in the Traceback error message is in the DataFrame's `'Host'` column which you included in the `X`  train/test values. Did you intend on doing that? Does that data need to be part of the `scaler.fit` data?

Comment: `Is it because I didn't convert the dataset into dataframe?` - No, the [example in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) shows a *regular* Python list being used for the argument.

Comment: I just realized the error came from the Host and not the IP Source :( @wwii (I actually used the host as it is without encoding), but when I use encoding techinque, it shows TypeError. After asking my professor, she recommended me to extract the features of the host and Full request URL instead of encoding it immediately. So I guess the main concern of this question is solved :) Thank you